# custom RStudio exit strategy for a given project

Tags: r, rstudio, rdata

In RStudio you can configure whether or not to save the `.RData` file on exit. I generally do not like to save the R project's `.RData` file on exit so I have set that option accordingly in `Preferences > General > Basic: Workspace` (on Mac). I do however would like to save it for some specific projects.  I was wondering if I can specify that in `.Rproj.user` or somewhere. I understand that I can save the objects and reload them, but that's suboptimal for my usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open a `.Rproj` with a text editor. It looks like this:

```
Version: 1.0

RestoreWorkspace: Yes
SaveWorkspace: Yes
AlwaysSaveHistory: Default

EnableCodeIndexing: Yes
UseSpacesForTab: Yes
NumSpacesForTab: 2
Encoding: UTF-8

RnwWeave: Sweave
LaTeX: pdfLaTeX
```

I changed the values for `RestoreWorkspace` and `SaveWorkspace` to accomplish what you want. [Documentation on this is a bit spotty](https://community.rstudio.com/t/documentation-about-rproj-files/29250/2), to say the least, but the values which are in there by default are self-explanatory.